# cant hide controller for quicktime using html

Tags: html, quicktime

I want to display .MOV file and I am using Quicktime. User wants the controller to be hidden and I have set the attribute Controller = "False" but it won't hide. Any help on this issue? your help is much appreciated. here is my html:

```
<object classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab" height="645" width="447"> 
    <param name="src" value="video.mov">
    <param name="autoplay" value="true">
    <param name="target" value="myself">
    <param name="CONTROLLER" value="FALSE">
    <param name="Loop" value="True">
    <param name="href" value="video.mov">
    <param name="type" value="video/quicktime">
    <embed src="video.mov" 
    height="645" 
    width="447" 
    autoplay="true" 
    CONTROLLER="FALSE" LOOP="True"
    type="video/quicktime" 
    pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/" 
     href="video.mov" 
    target="myself"></embed> 
</object>
```